# Circular dependency between the following tasks

Tags: android, gradle

I try to solve this problem for more than 5 hours. What could be the problem?

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:checkManifestChangesDevelopDebug
\--- :app:instantRunMainApkResourcesDevelopDebug
     \--- :app:transformClassesAndDexWithShrinkResForDevelopDebug
          \--- :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDevelopDebug
               +--- :app:preColdswapDevelopDebug
               |    \--- :app:incrementalDevelopDebugTasks
               |         +--- :app:transformClassesAndClassesEnhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDevelopDebug
               |         |    \--- :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDevelopDebug
               |         |         \--- :app:checkManifestChangesDevelopDebug (*)
               |         \--- :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDevelopDebug (*)
               \--- :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDevelopDebug
                    +--- :app:preColdswapDevelopDebug (*)
                    \--- :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDevelopDebug (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

I added:

> org.gradle.configureondemand=true

But the problem is still present

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

static def getFullDate() {
    return new Date().format('dd.MM.yyyy-HH.mm')
}

static def getDate() {
    return new Date().format('dd.MM.yyyy')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.MYPROJECT"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 47
        versionName "2.11d"
//      project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "MYPROJECT_" + versionName + "_" + getFullDate())
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "MYPROJECT_" + versionName + "_" + getDate())
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {

        prod {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_BASE_URL', '"http://MYPROJECT.com/"'
            dimension "app"
        }

        develop {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_BASE_URL', '"http://MYPROJECT.com/"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'YOUTUBE_API_KEY', '"AIzaSyD5eJIAcqUtMkBoorw_K8mh1d_TQSgjRwMT"'
            applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix = "-dev"
            dimension "app"
        }

    }
    dexOptions {
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.butterKnifeVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.butterKnifeVersion"
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //Google Supports
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    //Network
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.okhttpVersion"

    //Constraint layout
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"

    //Google services
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$rootProject.googleServiceVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.googleServiceVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$rootProject.googleServiceVersion"

    //RxJava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"

    //Lifecycle
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$project.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$project.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$project.lifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$project.lifecycleVersion"

    //Dagger dependencies
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.daggerVersion"

    //RxPermissions
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5@aar'

    //RxBinding
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'

    //TIMBER

    //implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.0'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"

    //Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$rootProject.glideVersion"
    implementation files('src/main/jniLibs/aacdecoder-android-0.8.jar')

    //Youtube
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    //Vitamio video player

    //implementation project(':vitamio')

    //VideoPlayer
    implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.2.12'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.splatte:ViewPagerIndicator:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.tablayouthelper:tablayouthelper:0.7.0'

    //Rate App
    implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.vbartacek:aacdecoder-android:0.8'
    implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.11'
    implementation 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //RouteController
    implementation 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:3.0.0-RC3'

    //Joda Time
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.4'

    //ReactLocation
    implementation 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location2:2.1@aar'

    //SeekBar
    implementation 'com.xw.repo:bubbleseekbar:3.16-lite'

    //Lombok

    //Warning! Versions above 1.16.20 do not work with lambda (throws an exception when compiling)
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$rootProject.lombokVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$rootProject.lombokVersion"

    //nv-websocket-client
    implementation "com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:$rootProject.nvWebSocketClientVersion"

    //Custom tabs
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    //Auto scroll view pager for Suggestion
    implementation("cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:$rootProject.autoScrollViewPagerVersion") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    //Paging library
    implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:$rootProject.pagingLibraryVersion"

    //Beacon Library
    implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.15'
}
```

and build.gradle (Project: myproject)

> // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common
>   to all sub-projects/modules.
>
> ```
> buildscript {
> repositories {
>     maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
>     mavenCentral()
>     jcenter()
>     google()
>
>     maven {
>         url 'https://maven.google.com/'
>         name 'Google'
>     }
>     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
> }
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
>     classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.1.0"
>     classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
>     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>     // in the individual module build.gradle files
> } }
>
> allprojects {
> repositories {
>     maven {
>         url 'https://maven.google.com/'
>         name 'Google'
>     }
>     maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
>     mavenCentral()
>     jcenter()
>
>     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
> }
> subprojects {
>     project.configurations.all {
>         resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
>             if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
>                     && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
>                 details.useVersion "27.1.1"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> } }
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
> delete rootProject.buildDir }
>
> // Define versions in a single place ext {
> // Sdk and tools
> minSdkVersion = 19
> targetSdkVersion = 27
> compileSdkVersion = 27
> buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
>
> // App dependencies
> supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
> butterKnifeVersion = '8.8.1'
> retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
> okhttpVersion = '3.8.0'
> junitVersion = '4.12'
> glideVersion = '4.7.1'
> googleServiceVersion = '15.0.1'
> permissionDispatcherVersion = '3.1.0'
> rxjavaVersion = '2.1.12'
> rxandroidVersion = '2.0.2'
> lifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
> daggerVersion = '2.16'
> pagingLibraryVersion = '1.0.1'
> autoScrollViewPagerVersion = '1.1.2'
> nvWebSocketClientVersion = '2.5'
> lombokVersion = '1.16.20'
> constraintLayoutVersion = '1.1.3' }
> ```

Comment: The `Circular dependency` refers to the fact that the task `:app:checkManifestChangesDevelopDebug`, through its dependencies listed in that graph, will eventually lead to itself being called again. We'll need to see your `build.gradle` to try to make sense of _why_ the circular dependency exists.

Comment: @bto I updated my question

Comment: @TouhidulIslam Have you solved this ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

*This happens when **a module** depends on **itself**!*

For example, suppose this for module **`app`**:

```
// ...
dependencies {
    implementation project(':app') // 'app' depends on 'app' !!!
    // ...
}
```

---

Or maybe `x` module depends on `y` and `y` depends on `x`!

Or even longer: `x -> y -> z -> ... -> x`!!

Comment: My problem was I was imported module data into app and module app into data

Comment: In my case, I was using plugin from buildSrc that contained common dependency for the module itself

Comment: `compile` is deprecated.

Comment: @ArifMustafa; Replaced with `implementation`.

Comment: This Fixed My Problem I was Searching for this in my current Project module but this line was found in some added Modules and because of this it showing Error Thank you

Answer (score 17):

But minifyEnabled is important in production. I have tried the following arrangement and it worked with instant run enabled:

```
minifyEnabled true
useProguard true
shrinkResources false
```

So this tends to happen when instant Run is enabled and shrinkResources is set to true as well.

Answer (score 3):

For errors such this:

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks::app:bundleDebugClasses
\--- :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
     \--- :package_name:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
          \--- :package_name:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
               \--- :app:bundleDebugClasses (*)
```

This error occurs because you have created a cycle between dependencies. This means two `implementations` that one belongs to the other is used, so you should remove additional `implementation` from below `build.gradle` in list of **gradles**.
Another example:
If **package A** is implemented in **package B** and also you needed to put **B** implementation in **A** and you did that, it makes this error.

Answer (score 2):

minified, userProguard, shrink resources can produce errors in debug mode. These features are needed to be used in Release version. So you need to disable them or you can add debuggable=false.

```
debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

My IntelliJ had added to `build.gradle`

```
implementation project(path: ':')
```

Removing it solved this

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Just had to be replaced

```
minifyEnabled true 
useProguard true 
shrinkResources true
```

on

```
minifyEnabled false 
useProguard false 
shrinkResources false
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into Project structure.(Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S) and remove imported module > sync project and gradle files

add `build.gradle Module:app`

```
implementation project(':app')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you might get this error is trying to build a submodule directly in the submodule folder and not from the parent project.

e.g. you've the rootproject at ProjectA and the submodule project called ProjectB in ProjectA/ProjectB

in `ProjectA/ProjectB/build.gradle` you depend on the root project like so:

```
dependencies {
    implementation rootProject
}
```

and in `ProjectA/settings.gradle` you have ProjectB as a subproject

```
rootProject.name = 'ProjectA'
include 'ProjectB'
```

If you try and `gradlew build` from the `ProjectA/ProjectB/` directory, you'll get the `Circular dependency between the following tasks` error.

But if you just `gradlew build` from the `ProjectA/` directory, it should build file and output the ProjectB JAR to the `ProjectA/ProjectB/build/libs` folder.